# Recommended jquery form frameworks

Tags: jquery, forms

can you recommend me some nice, useful, and updated jQuery form frameworks or builders ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? A bit of context often helps provide much better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're asking. Your question is pretty vague.

I use this plugin for submitting forms via ajax. It extends the normal ajax and serialize functionality nicely.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: Thanks... Form builders like jformer.

Answer (score 0):

jquery IS the framework, what you need is a plugin.
I recommend [jqTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried this one, but its GPL3, HTML5 oriented and has proper documentation:
http://demos.kendoui.com/

Will definitely give it a try in near future.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a library and there are plenty for form frameworks written on top of it such as jformer.com and alpacajs.org.

I haven't yet used any of them but jFormer looks good.